# DOCKER environment in production

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, redis, microservices

I am new to docker and just started playing around it. I have a following setup of my app in production as of now:

Server machine 1 : running spring-boot microservices

Server machine 2 : running redis

Server machine 3 : running postgres

If I use docker in server machine 1 and run all of the microservices as container and run the redis and postgres as a container as well in server machine 1, is this is correct thing to do ?  Or I have to run the docker on all the server machines and run containers separately.

Which is the best practice to do ?

Comment: If you treat Docker Container as another OS, you can see clearly that you can do either - keep all in one server, or divide them into separate servers. I personally keep all of them in one server and then spawn another server only when I need to scale the services. That also saves money.

Comment: In which scenario I can add up the new server ? And how I am going to connect docker in both servers ?

Comment: For that most people use Kubernetes or Docker swarm. Those programs deploy your docker containers on multiple machines, without you having to thing too much about connecting those.

Answer (score 4):

When first starting out I suggest doing it all on 1 machine. Your database containers can use volumes to save data to the machine itself. So when you need to switch to a different machine, because 1 machine is too slow, you can easily transfer your database data. When starting to use more than 1 machine to run Docker you probably want to use a deployment option like Kubernetes or Docker swarm. This will simplify the process of setting up your environments on different machines, because it will be done by Kubernetes.

Also when your application is getting a lot of traffic you might want to switch to Managed Databases, which are provided by services like GCP, AWS, Digitalocean, etc. A managed database will scale automatically, get updates frequently and back-up automatically. This will take a lot of burden of your shoulders. I personally use Managed Databases myself.

My suggestion for now: Use 1 machine, learn Kubernetes when your application gets more traffic. Look into managed databases (available for Redis and Postgres).